# How to calculate correlation between two variables with different sample size

Tags: r, correlation

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2)
corr <- cor(a,b)
```

I have two time series variables and want to compute the correlation, but they have different sample sizes. To simplify my problem, consider if there are two variables `a`, `b` and I want to calculate correlation between `a` and `b` but I only want to the first two values. How do I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 5):

If you're *sure* that the starting point of both time series is the same (and there are no skipped values), then

```
n <- min(length(a),length(b))
cor(a[seq(n)],b[seq(n)])
```

should work to truncate both variables to the length of the shorter one.