# Correlate two variables between two dataframe with different sample size

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to make a correlation between two dataframes.

Let me show an example:
Here are my two dataframes

```
set.seed(123) 
v1<- c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 3))
v2<- c(rnorm(4), rnorm(3))

df1 <- data.frame(v1, v2)

v1<- c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 5))
v2<- c(rnorm(3), rnorm(5))

df2 <- data.frame(v1, v2)
```

I would like to correlate "a" modalities between df1 and df2 and do the same for "b" and so on. I could do it manually but I have hundreds of different modalities in my variable v1.

Another issue is sometimes I have different sizes between both dataframes.

For instance, in df1 we have "a" repeated four times while in df2 it is repeated three times.

I would like to correlate always based on the dataframe having the minimum modality size and discard the other on the dataframe having more like in this stackoverflow example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027633/how-to-calculate-correlation-between-two-variables-with-different-sample-size)
Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the correlation between the "a" modalities in df1 and df2, you can first subset the data for each dataframe by the values in the v1 column:

```
df1_a <- df1[df1$v1 == "a", ]
df2_a <- df2[df2$v1 == "a", ]
```

Then, you can calculate the correlation using the cor() function, which calculates the Pearson correlation coefficient between two variables:

```
cor(df1_a$v2, df2_a$v2)
```

If the sizes of the data frames are different, you can take the minimum of the two sizes and use that to subset the data before calculating the correlation:

```
n <- min(nrow(df1_a), nrow(df2_a))
cor(df1_a$v2[1:n], df2_a$v2[1:n])
```

To do this for all modalities in the v1 column, you can use a for loop to iterate over all unique values in the v1 column and calculate the correlations for each modality:

```
modalities <- unique(df1$v1)

correlations <- list()

for (modality in modalities) {
  df1_subset <- df1[df1$v1 == modality, ]
  df2_subset <- df2[df2$v1 == modality, ]
  n <- min(nrow(df1_subset), nrow(df2_subset))
  correlations[[modality]] <- cor(df1_subset$v2[1:n], df2_subset$v2[1:n])
}

correlations
```

This will create a list of correlations for each modality, with the modality names as the names of the list elements.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great. Could you select it as best answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `dplyr`

- First attach a group to the list of both data frames.
- Then get the group size for later filtering of row numbers in groups.
- Finally get the correlation for the matching groups.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(grp = 1), df2 %>% mutate(grp = 2)) %>% 
  group_by(v1, grp) %>% 
  mutate(size = n(), rown = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(v1) %>% 
  mutate(minsize = min(size)) %>% 
  filter(rown <= minsize) %>% 
  summarize(corr = cor(v2[grp == 1], v2[grp == 2]))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  v1      corr
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a      0.819
2 b     -0.693
```